# Ruby on rails tag functions. Why does the case of radio_button_tag.id not match label.for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, case-sensitive

While registering for openstreetmap, on the terms page, I noticed that clicking the labels didn't check the radio buttons associated with them. Here is the html:

```
<!-- legale is GB --> 
<form action="/user/terms" method="post"> 
  <p> 
    Please select your country of residence:

    <input id="legale_fr" name="legale"
onchange="Element.update(&quot;contributorTerms&quot;, &quot;&lt;img alt=\&quot;Searching\&quot; src=\&quot;/images/searching.gif?1313181320\&quot; /&gt;&quot;);; new Ajax.Request('/user/terms?legale=FR', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true})" 
                                            type="radio" value="FR" /> 
    <label for="legale_FR">France</label>

    <input id="legale_it" name="legale" ... type="radio" value="IT" /> 
    <label for="legale_IT">Italy</label> 

    <input checked="checked"
           id="legale_gb" name="legale" ... type="radio" value="GB" /> 
    <label for="legale_GB">Rest of the world</label> 
  </p> 
</form>
```

As you can see the checkbox `id="legale_gb"` doesn't match the label `for="legale_GB"`.

Now openstreetmap's website is actually open source so we can read the [terms.html.erb](http://git.openstreetmap.org/rails.git/blob/HEAD:/app/views/user/terms.html.erb#l9):

```
<!-- legale is <%= @legale %> -->
<% form_tag :action => 'terms' do %>
  <p>
    <%= t 'user.terms.legale_select' %>
    <% [['france', 'FR'], ['italy', 'IT'], ['rest_of_world', 'GB']].each do |name,legale| %>
      <%=
        radio_button_tag 'legale', legale, @legale == legale,
          :onchange => remote_function(
            :before => update_page do |page|
              page.replace_html 'contributorTerms', image_tag('searching.gif')
            end,
            :url => {:legale => legale}
          )
      %>
      <%= label_tag "legale_#{legale}", t('user.terms.legale_names.' + name) %>
    <% end %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I'm a rails newbie, but I can't see anything there that lowercases the `id` of the radio button tag. What's more, even when I look at the source of [radio_button_tag](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83d9398ec049e414ce5797b6bd00fda384705109/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L365), [sanitize_to_id](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83d9398ec049e414ce5797b6bd00fda384705109/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L659) I can't see where this is coming from.

Anyone got any idea what's causing this?

*Edit* Swapped out `label` for `radio` in my description according to answer from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things:

1. Wrong tag, the offender is `radio_button_tag` (it's capped as expected in the label).
2. Seems like you're linking to the wrong Rails.  According to this project's [environment.rb](http://git.openstreetmap.org/rails.git/blob/HEAD:/config/environment.rb#l4), it's using Rails 2.3.14.  If you look at [radio_button_tag](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v2.3.14/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L317) for that release, you'll see the culprit.

   ```
   # our pretty tag value is downcased on line 318
   pretty_tag_value = value.to_s.gsub(/\s/, "_").gsub(/(?!-)\W/, "").downcase

   # although the pretty name is not, oddly
   pretty_name = name.to_s.gsub(/\[/, "_").gsub(/\]/, "")

   # then the two are combined into the HTML id
   html_options = { ..., "id" => "#{pretty_name}_#{pretty_tag_value}", ... }
   ```

Comment: Nice answer, I didn't know how to investigate which version they are using.

Comment: Yeah it took me a minute to remember where it was defined myself.  Rails 2 feels like ages ago.